# What namespace do I need to import in code behind vb asp.net to get a session value

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

Here is my code, session is not working, what is missing?
regards

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

End Class

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    End Sub
    Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbconnection").ConnectionString)

        con.Open()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from nfl where UserName =@username and Password=@password", con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUserName.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPWD.Text)
        Session["password"] =  txtPWD.Text;
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        da.Fill(dt)
        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Response.Redirect("Details.aspx")
        Else
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.[GetType](), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Invalid Username and Password')</script>")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: There is no `session` object in your snippet. So what are you actually asking?

Comment: I mean what class i need to import for session works? its marked as an error

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Session["password"] =  txtPWD.Text;  its marked  red underlined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your not using C#.

This:

```
Session["password"] = txtPWD.Text;
```

should be:

```
Session("password") = txtPWD.Text
```